# Multi Substring from long string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a long string I need to take out only substrings that are between `{` and `}`, and turn it into a Json object

This string

```
    sys=t85,fggh{"Name":"5038.zip","Folder":"Root",,"Download":"services/DownloadFile.ashx?"} dsdfg x=565,dfg 
{"Name":"5038.zip","Folder":"Root",,"Download":"services/DownloadFile.ashx?"}dfsdfg567
{"Name":"5038.zip","Folder":"Root",,"Download":"services/DownloadFile.ashx?"}sdfs
```

I have trash inside so I need to extract the substring of the data between `{` and `}`

My code is here, but I'm stuck, I can't remove the data that I already taken.

```
List<JsonTypeFile> AllFiles = new List<JsonTypeFile>();
int lenght = -1;

while (temp.Length>3)
{
    lenght = temp.IndexOf("}") - temp.IndexOf("{");
    temp=temp.Substring(temp.IndexOf("{"), lenght+1);
    temp.Remove(temp.IndexOf("{"), lenght + 1);
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SnSafe.JsonTypeFile>(temp);
    AllFiles.Add(result);
}
```

Comment: String methods do not change the string itself, so `temp = temp.Remove`. However it is not entirely clear why do you need this `Remove` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want to extract anything in-between the braces and ignore anything else.

The following regular expression should allow you to extract that info:

`{[^}]*}` *(a brace, followed by anything that isn't a brace, followed by a brace)*

You can extract all instances and then deserialize them using something along the lines of:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

List<JsonTypeFile> AllFiles = new List<JsonTypeFile>();

foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(temp, "{[^}]*}"))
{
  var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SnSafe.JsonTypeFile>(match.Value);
  AllFiles.Add(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or using regex you can get the strings like this:

```
        var regex = new Regex("{([^}]*)}");
        var matches = regex.Matches(str);
        var list = (from object m in matches select m.ToString().Replace("{",string.Empty).Replace("}",string.Empty)).ToList();
        var jsonList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

The *str* variable containing your string as you provided in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex for this but what I would do is use `.split ('{')` to split into sections, skip the first section, and then using .split('}) to find the first portion of each section.

You can do this using LINQ

```
var data = temp
    .Split('{')
    .Skip(1)
    .Select(v => v.Split('}').FirstOrDefault());
```